# Why map out of variable gets compile error, whereas in variable it compiles OK?

Tags: reactjs

Why in the first case it compiles OK, but in the second it gets compile error?
What I've done is just get map out of variable. Just can't understand it.

> Line 22:  'movie' is not defined  no-undef

```
class Movies extends Component {
  render() {
    let movieItems = this.props.movies.map(movie => {
      return <MovieItem key={movie.id} movie={movie} />;
    });
    return <div style={flex}>{movieItems}</div>;
  }
}

class Movies extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={flex}>
        this.props.movies.map((movie)=>{
          <MovieItem key={movie.id} movie={movie} />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to wrap it here. If you want to render js in between HTML code you will have to make use of *{ }*

```js
class Movies extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={flex}>
                {this.props.movies.map((movie) => {
                    <MovieItem key={movie.id} movie={movie}/>
                    })
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Movies
```

Answer (score 0):

Compilation error because you forgot to put the expression in `{}`, here:

```
<div>
   this.props.....
</div>
```

Another issue is you are not returning anything inside map body, so it will render nothing because by default map returns `undefined`.

Either use `return <MovieItem....`, or replace `{}` with `()`.

Write it like this:

```
class Movies extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={flex}>
         {
            this.props.movies.map((movie)=> (
               <MovieItem key={movie.id} movie={movie} />
            )
         }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this. Strange but ESlint expect "," here and treat {} like an object. But higher comment is OK.